# How to specify conditions inside np.where() when they themselves depend on some index?

Tags: numpy, conditional-statements, where-clause, logical-operators

I have many particles inside a sphere with known radius called `Sphere_Radius`. The mass, position, and 3d velocity arrays of these particles are known to be respectively `mass_array` with shape *(16658089, )*, and `position_array`, and `velocity_array` both with shapes *(16658089, 3)*. Also, particles are associated with some random numerical IDs. A function called *distances_Gas* produces an array whose elements are the distances between each gas particle and the center of the sphere.

Some pencil-like beam with a fixed square cross-section is piercing through the sphere along z-axis all the way across the sphere. I would like to calculate the mean velocity of all the particles inside this beam. The position of the sides of this beam is known (let's say the grid constrained by -1 <= x <= +1 and -1 <= y <= +1). But the problem I have is identifying all the particles that are inside this beam and then use their IDs to calculate the mean velocity inside beam. Assuming I know these IDs, here is my line of code to produce the mean velocity inside that beam:

```
np.array([np.tensordot(mass_array[i], velocity_array[i], axes=([0],[0])) for i in np.where(distances_Gas <= Sphere_Radius)])*pow(sum(sum(mass_array[i] for i in np.where(distances_Gas <= Sphere_Radius))), -1)
```

(Basically I am using *Sigma(m.v)/Sigma(m)* for the mean velocity)

However, `distances_Gas <= Sphere_Radius` is only one condition out of a total of three where the following two conditions (as mentioned earlier) are missing and I am not sure how to insert them in such a way that the code produces some `(1, 3)-shape` array representing mean velocity of the particles inside the beam:

-1 <= position_array[i][0] <= +1

-1 <= position_array[i][1] <= +1

Comment: `where` just looks for no zero vales in the argument. Constructing that array is a separate task. Logical and/or can be used to combine several arrays.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, do you mean that logical_and should be used inside where? The problem is that logical_and accepts only two conditions while I have three.

Comment: `D = A & B & C` `where(D)`

Comment: When I define D this way, I am receiving this error message: "NameError: name 'i' is not defined" since there is a running index i corresponding to each particle.

Comment: D = (distances_Gas <= Sphere_Radius) & (-1 <= np.array([item[0] for item in position_array]) <= 1) & (-1 <= np.array([item[1] for item in position_array]) <= 1) is my defined D then. However, here is the output when running it in an ipython shell:  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()